# Content too long for table in Reportlab

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

This is an example of my question.

[Click here to check out the problem in my PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXoKv.jpg)

```
    from reportlab.lib import colors
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table
    
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf")
    element = []
    
    data = [["Testing Table", ""], ["Short content", "This is a short content."],["Long content", "aaaaaaaaaaaaa This is a super long content which I dont know how to 
            automaticaly make it fit my A4 page. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]]
    t = Table(data, style=[("BOX", (0, 1), (-1, -1), 2, colors.black),
                           ("GRID", (0, 1), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
                           ("ALIGN", (0, 0), (0, -1), "CENTER"),
                           ("VALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "MIDDLE"),
                           ("ALIGN", (1, 1), (1, -1), "LEFT")])
    element.append(t)
    doc.build(element)
```

Comment: You can try preprocessing the text with pythons built in [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your long text (or all texts) in a `Paragraph` object.

To save myself from repeating `Pragraph("...", style)`, I've created a function `P(txt)`.

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("test.pdf")
element = []
style = getSampleStyleSheet()['Normal']

def P(txt):
    return Paragraph(txt, style)

data = [[P("Testing Table"), ""], [P("Short content"), P("This is a short content.")],
 [P("Long content"), P("aaaaaaaaaaaaa This is a super long content which I dont know how to automaticaly make it fit my A4 page. aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")]]
t = Table(data, style=[("BOX", (0, 1), (-1, -1), 2, colors.black),
                        ("GRID", (0, 1), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
                        ("ALIGN", (0, 0), (0, -1), "CENTER"),
                        ("VALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "MIDDLE"),
                        ("ALIGN", (1, 1), (1, -1), "LEFT")])
element.append(t)
doc.build(element)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Old answer but still its working, Can't get resolution from ChatGPT or Bard, but above answer will work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an option provided in `reportlab`, but you can do it externally by using the `textwrap` module.

Input data:

```
data = [["Testing Table", ""],
        ["Short content", "This is a short content."],
        ["Long content", "aaaaaaaaaaaaa This is a super long content which I dont know how to automaticaly make it fit my A4 page.aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"]]
```

Processing:

```
data = [(header, '\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(content, width=70))) for header, content in data]
```

The `textwrap.wrap` breaks up lines that are longer than 70 characters.  And the `join` adds them together using the linebreak character (`\n`).

Which results in an output format:

[image]